# Multithreading Models - One to Many model

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, one-to-many

I've been reading the dinosaur book and have been confused by this particular model.

The books says that for the one to many model "Thread management is done by the thread library in user space, so it is efficient; but the entire process will block if a thread makes a blocking system call. Also, because only one thread can access the kernel at a time, multiple threads are unable to run in parallel on multiprocessors"

What I'm confused about is what is meant by an entire process will block if a blocking system call is made? Does this mean if I have a multi-threaded program and one of it's threads blocks then all of its threads will have to wait, effectively stalling the program?

If a program undergoing execution causes a block with this model does it mean that another separate program can't be swapped in to be executed because the kernel thread is blocking? If that answer is YES another program(process) could be swapped in than why couldn't a multi-threaded program simply execute another one of its threads while the blocking thread is forced to wait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you manage your threads in user level, it means that the swapping is done by your application, not by OS scheduler. Each thread must reach some point where he surrenders (or loses) the control to the management mechanism, but that mechanism is also user-level, so if one of the threads is in the middle of doing a system call - your thread management system (and through that all the other threads) must wait until the kernel code is done.

The OS is still active all the time, and may still preempt the entire program, so other processes will not starve, only the internal "threads" you manage yourself. These threads can't get started during that block because the mechanism responsible of starting them is also blocked by the kernel.

Comment: So what type of system call would cause a thread to block and make all the other threads in the program wait but still allow a another program to be swapped in and be executed in the mean time. I don't get why the kernel can handle a thread from a separate process that is swapped in but not a different thread from a program where one of its threads is blocking.

To me it seems like if the kernel is tied up with a blocking thread than no thread from any other program should be able to execute not just the threads belonging to the same program that has the blocking thread.

Comment: Any syscall. The kernel doesn't know there are multiple threads in your program, as far as it's concerned it's a single thread in a single process. The internal thread scheduler calls and "switches" are not different than any other user function call. Another perspective is that to get a realtime preemption you need the OS (unless you bypass that with a trick), and once you involve the OS you beat the whole purpose of user-level fast context switches. Other processes do that, with the regular penalty, and your process can preempt someone else too, but the fast switch require full ownership.

Comment: You said "Each thread must reach some point where he surrenders (or loses) the control to the management mechanism, but that mechanism is also user-level, so if one of the threads is in the middle of doing a system call - your thread management system (and through that all the other threads) must wait until the kernel code is done."

So if the management system forces all the threads of a program to wait because one of them blocks. Why is the management system able to switch to another program and begin handling threads belonging to it. What happens to the thread that was blocking?

Comment: The way I WANT to think about it is if you have a bunch of user threads all being funneled to a single kernel thread. If one of the user thread makes a blocking call that single kernel thread should be tied up with the blocking thread. Thereby shutting all other threads from any process out until the block is done.